# Django Form Showing No Input Fields

Tags: python, django, forms, django-templates

I am getting a valid response back when requesting my form, but I am getting no form fields with the response. It is loading the *Submit button only*, but no form fields.

Goal: get form fields to load and be able to submit form.

I have a **views.py**:

```
 def Registration(request):
    form = NewUserRegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/Login/")
    else:
        form = NewUserRegistrationForm()

    return render(request, 'VA/reuse/register.html', {
        'form': form 
    })
```

**forms.py**

```
class NewUserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(required=True,max_length=30,validators=[RegexValidator('^[A-Za-z0-9]{1,30}$','e.g. must be 30 characters or less','Invalid Entry')])
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, max_length=75)
    password = forms.PasswordInput()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1","password2")

def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(NewUserRegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
    user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
    user.password = self.cleaned_data["password1"]
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

a **template**

```
<div id="register_bubble">
    <form method="post" id="userRegistration">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ NewUserRegForm.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form> <!-- /RegistrationForm (FORM) -->
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'm getting no error while in debug mode locally either.

Thank you!

Comment: Don't edit your question after it has been answered....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two mistakes.

Firstly, you're passing the form class into the template context, not the form instance: the class is `NewUserRegistrationForm`, but you've instantiated it as `NewUserRegForm`, and that's what you should be passing as the value in the form context.

To make it more complicated, the key name you've given to that value is also `NewUserRegistrationForm` - but you're still referring to `NewUserRegForm` in the template, even though that doesn't exist there.

This would be much more obvious if you used PEP8 compliant names. Instances should be lower case with underscore: eg `new_user_registration_form`. However, in this case you could just call it `form`, since there's only one.

```
return render(request, 'mysite/reuse/register.html', {
    'NewUserRegForm': NewUserRegForm 
})
```

or, better:

```
form = NewUserRegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
...
return render(request, 'mysite/reuse/register.html', {
    'form': form 
})
```

Comment: Can you show me exactly what I'm doing wrong in code? I would really appreciate it Daniel

Comment: This is exceptionally easier to understand Daniel. good idea with the PEP8 naming, I'll have to remember that in the future. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I made a similar mistake to OP and this really helped clarify!

Answer (score 3):

You're passing the form instance to the context as `'form'`, but calling it in the template as `{{ NewUserRegForm.as_p }}`.

You should use `{{ form.as_p }}` instead.