# Django 1.9 forms not displaying in template but CSRF token is

Tags: django, forms, django-1.9

I'm working on a Django project and I'm having issues with my Model Forms rendering in my template. I've read [through the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/), tutorials as well as searched here; particularly this post here someone [had with their input fields not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18806668/django-form-showing-no-input-fields). I thought that my issue was similar but I'm still not having any success. Basically, when I call `{{ form.as_p }}` nothing shows in the DOM. This occurs despite my csrf token working. Here's the code for my Model:

```
class Workout(models.Model):
upper_body = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text="ex: Bench Press, Shoulder Press, Shrugs")
lower_body = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text="Squats, Lunges, Deadlifts")
explosive = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text="Hang Cleans, Box Jumps, Hang Snatch")
cardio = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text="Jogging, Cycling, 110s")
speed = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text="Sprints, 10 yard starts, Speed Sled")
skill = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text="Boxing, Jump Shooting, Route Running")
athlete = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='athlete')

def __unicode__(self):
    return u"{}".format(self.athlete)
```

Here is the `forms.py` for that Model:

```
from django import forms
from .models import User, Workout, Meal
from django.forms import ModelForm

# Beginning of Workout Form

class WorkoutForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Workout
        fields = ["upper_body",
                  "lower_body",
                  "explosive",
                  "cardio",
                  "speed",
                  "skill"]

# End of Workout Form
```

Here is my `views.py` for the form:

```
from .models import User, Workout, Meal
from Spartan.forms import UserForm, WorkoutForm, MealForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseForbidden, HttpResponseRedirect

def workout_form(request):
    form = WorkoutForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        workout = form.save(commit=False)
        workout.athlete = request.user
        workout.save()
        return redirect('user/workouts.html')
```

Here is the actual the form that should be rendered on the template:

```
<div class="container">
    <h3>Create your workout</h3>
    <form method="POST" action=".">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {{ form.as_p }}

    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Create Your Workout">CREATE WORKOUT</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

As I've stated, the token is there, along with the form and button just no input fields. If anyone can assist me in pointing out what I'm not doing or what I'm overlooking it'll be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: In the `else` part of the view, add the parenthesis, construct the form object - `form = WorkoutForm()`

Comment: @JRodDynamite's suggestion should fix the problem, but you don't actually need that `else` block at all. You are already doing `form = WorkoutForm(request.POST or None)` which creates a form for POST and GET requests.

Comment: @Alasdair - Yup, you are right. Didn't notice that. So, simply removing the `else` block should resolves the OP's question.

Comment: Thanks @Alasdair and @JRodDynamite I removed the `else` block and it's still not rendering.

Comment: Apart from the `else` block, I cant' spot any problems in your code. Hope you figure out the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Alasdair I appreciate it. I'll update if I figure out the issue. Last resort is to use HTML forms and validate with JavaScript. Would prefer to do it the Django-way though.

Comment: athlete appears to be a required field but is not in your list of fields for the form.  What happens if you add it?

Comment: Hey @PhoebeB, I just added that and still no input is displayed. I even displayed the output of the CSRF token, `{{ csrf_token }}` and it displayed fine. Just no input fields for my Model Form. I keep reading over the documentation and checking out various tutorials to see if I overlooked something simple but I can't find anything obvious. I also changed the form to `{{ WorkoutForm.as_p }}` and that didn't work and neither did `{{ workout_form.as_p }}` for good measure. Nothing displays the form.

Comment: Are you rendering form to the same html page as per the view that renders the form?

Comment: Hi @cutteeth, I'm rendering to the `user/workouts.html`. That's the view where the form is to display. I want that page to be where users enter their workout info and I'll display that info on a separate page. Just can't get the form inputs to display. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your view. The `else` block doesn't matter because in your GET request `is_valid` is always returning `False` and you're redirecting to `user/workouts.html` *without context*.

One solution is to use an if/else statement to segment how you handle GET and POST:

```
def workout_form(request):
    form = WorkoutForm() # Will be overridden if `is_valid` returns `False`
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = WorkoutForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            workout = form.save(commit=False)
            workout.athlete = request.user
            workout.save()
            return redirect('user/workouts.html')

    return render(request, 'user/workouts.html',
              {'form': form})
```

Comment: I just tried the `if/else` statement and the form is still not rendering. Frustrating. I tried your above example. Thinking about trying to redirect with context next.

Comment: @Long_Live_King you can't redirect with context in Django. Have you put a debugger in your code? If you're using the exact code I gave in my example, what is the value of `form` just above `return render(request.....` - you should also confirm that `is_valid` is returning `False` when you try to GET the blank form. Is that the case?

Comment: I tried the code you had and got a 200 request(consistently been the case) for `POST` along with a 304 for `GET`. I haven't tried a debugger just yet.

Comment: Put the line `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` right before `return render...` and make sure your `form` object actually contains an empty form. Then make sure you've changed back to using `form.as_p` vs. `workout_form.as_p` per your comments.

Comment: Sorry for taking awhile to respond. Continuing to get a 200 request when using `pdb.set_trace()`. Trying Class-Based Views now to see if that'll work.

Comment: @Long_Live_King so the debugger doesn't even stop the function here?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Silly mistake on my part. Basically had a view written for the page that was rendering while I styled it. Completely forgot it was being called and the function for the `workout_form` wasn't even being used. That's also why the `pdb.set_trace()` wasn't running either. All is well now. Thanks to everyone who assisted.